# Search google contact using People Api v3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I'm trying to use google People API to search a person by her/his name field. Here is the code sample:

```
service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)
request = service.people().searchContacts(pageSize=10, query="A", readMask="names")
print(request.body) # results in None, but there is a lot of contacts in my list starting from "A".
```

I used the following links:

https://developers.google.com/people/v1/contacts#python

https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/people_v1.people.html#get

https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python

and the SCOPE is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly.

I need a way to return a list of contacts using name mask (for ex, person with the name "Foo bar" should be found using "f", "F", "foo", and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You aren't executing your request, only referencing it.*

#### More Information:

In Python, a method without a defined `return` will always return `None`.

As you are not making the request, no return value is being obtained and so you are seeing `none` displayed.

#### Code Fix:

You need to execute the request like so:

```
service.people().searchContacts(pageSize=10, query="A", readMask="names").execute()
```

Also, the response object has no property `body`, so you will need to use

```
print(request.results)
```

to view the response text.